# Plotting StackedColumnGraph of visiblox in WP7 dynamically

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-3.0, visiblox

I am facing a problem in binding the values to the  StackedColumnGraph of visiblox in WP7 dynamically.

### the XAML code has hard coded values..

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NoBorder" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    </Style>

    <local:PartyList x:Key="Labour" >
        <local:ElectionResult Year="1997" VotesMillions="13.5" />
        <local:ElectionResult Year="2001" VotesMillions="10.7" />
        <local:ElectionResult Year="2005" VotesMillions="9.6" />
        <local:ElectionResult Year="2010" VotesMillions="8.6"/>

</local:PartyList>

    <local:PartyList x:Key="Conservatives">
        <local:ElectionResult Year="1997" VotesMillions="9.6" />
        <local:ElectionResult Year="2001" VotesMillions="8.4" />
        <local:ElectionResult Year="2005" VotesMillions="8.8" />
        <local:ElectionResult Year="2010" VotesMillions="10.7"/>

    </local:PartyList>

    <local:PartyList x:Key="LibDem">
        <local:ElectionResult Year="1997" VotesMillions="5.2" />
        <local:ElectionResult Year="2001" VotesMillions="4.8" />
        <local:ElectionResult Year="2005" VotesMillions="6.0" />
        <local:ElectionResult Year="2010" VotesMillions="6.8"/>

    </local:PartyList>

    <local:PartyList x:Key="Others">
        <local:ElectionResult Year="1997" VotesMillions="2.9" />
        <local:ElectionResult Year="2001" VotesMillions="2.5" />
        <local:ElectionResult Year="2005" VotesMillions="2.8" />
        <local:ElectionResult Year="2010" VotesMillions="3.5"/>

    </local:PartyList>
```

I have a Collection where the fetched data from the service are stored,One thing I need to know how to bind those  values with these hard coded values to plot the graph...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the following blog post as that explains in general terms how to bind data to a Visiblox Charts.  In short, there's a few different options depending on at which level you're trying to do the binding but the BindableDataSeries is the basic building block.

http://www.visiblox.com/blog/2011/06/data-binding-with-visiblox-charts

[Disclaimer: I work for Visiblox]

Comment: can I have an example for binding Stacked column chart